# B2C Tenant Not Logging Out

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a B2C custom policy for authentication but I am having trouble getting a consistent complete logout. The only way I have been able to get a complete logout of single sign on is to use the common endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={our homepage}
```

Then when I login I see this

[image: sign in]

Then I click sign in and see this

[image: pick account]

but even this does not always work. Sometimes it does not redirect but just sits on the "you have been logged out" screen.

Using the logout endpoint given in our metadata endpoint does not work as expected. I see the sign in screen (first image) but I cannot choose which account to login with I just click the button to sign in. I assume this means single sign on logout has not worked.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tennant}/{b2c-policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={our homepage}
```

How can I either get the first one to work every time or the second one to logout completely?

EDIT: Sorry I should have mentioned I am using node.js/javascript but any url type solution will work also.  Also we are using B2C so the application is registered on that tenant.  There is no option for a lotout url on this page.
[image: application registration screen]

Comment: What does "complete logout of single sign on" mean? Do you have a single application from which you want to logout, or do you have multiple web apps using a Single Sign-In and now you need Single Sign-Out too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to logout the user from B2C, you need to redirect your user to the **B2C logout endpoint**, not to the common endpoint. This should look like:

```
https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p=b2c_1_sign_in&post_logout_redirect_uri={your homepage}
```

Be sure you **redirect the browser** to that endpoint and don't try to do a GET through a back-channel, otherwise it will not do anything as the Single Sign-in mechanism is based on browser cookies.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to configure single sign out? This can be done but requires configuration separate from the sign-on configuration.

In the Accounts Controller you need to add a SingleSignOut action.

```
public ActionResult SingleSignOut(string redirectUri)
        {
            if (redirectUri == null)
                ViewBag.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44308/";
            else
                ViewBag.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            return View();
        }
```

See [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out/) and the accompanying repository.

[This reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-out-protocol-reference) is also helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Sorry I forgot to add I am using node.js and the azure-passport-ad module but any url based solution will work. Your link mentions adding a signout url in the application portal but there is no option for this in my application.  We are using B2C so the app registration page is different.